# Java double x 10/4=2?

Tags: java, double

I am new to Java and I would like to know why when you have double 10/4 you get 2? Does double always have to have decimals in order to get the right answer? Thanks.

```
public class Super {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double x = 10/4;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Integer fail... erm... integer division...

Comment: The principle underlying all the answers is important. The value of a Java expression depends on the types and values of the operands. It does not depend on how the result will be used.

Answer (score 7):

You are performing integer division before assigning the result.  Integer division results in an `int`, the truncated result `2`.  To force floating point calculation and get `2.5`, use `double` literals:

```
double x = 10.0 / 4.0;
```

or cast one to a `double`:

```
double x = (double) 10 / 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing with integers. You can declare those as doubles the following way (or use `f` for floats):

```
double x = 10d/4d;
System.out.println(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer division. Even though you're assigning the result to a `double`, you're still dividing two integers (10 and 4) so you get an integer result (floor of the actual result).

You can fix this by having one or both operands be a floating point value, for example like this:

```
double x = 10.0/4;
```

or by using type casting:

```
double x = (double)10/4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace it by:

```
double x = 10.0/4.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Double always takes in a decimal. So it would have to be

```
public class Super {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double x = 10.0/4.0;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For double you need to use the following

```
10d/4d
```

Then the output is going to be 2.5 Otherwise you are just gonna end up diving two integers

Answer (score 0):

The right side ofter the '=' is an integer expression, which gets converted to double only after it's calculated.  So it calculates 10/4 as an integer, 2, and then converts that number to double.  If you want it as a double from the beginning you have to write

```
double x = 10.0 / 4.0;
```

Only numbers that cannot be read as integer will be treated as double.  Or even simpler

```
double x = 2.5; // :-)
```